# get previous row id using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

My requirement like this:

I have to fetch a row from table "A". Now I have to loop through all the rows and get the values from the `ID` column. If I get `ID = 5` then I want to execute some stored procedure through which I get the previous id row from some table "B". Like

```
select * from table b where ID = 4
```

Buy my question is: if someone deleted that row from the database (e.g. some user deleted the rows with id 3 and 4) - then how can I get the row with `id = 2` from the database?

Please give me some sql stored procedure to get previous id record from table.

Comment: You need to stop thinking of loooping through rows. You NEVER loop through rows if you can help it. Learn to do things in sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query should get it for you:

```
select max(ID) from YourTable where ID < @YourID
```

`@YourID` is a variable containing your recently inserted ID

Answer (score 4):

Hard to understand exactly what it is your looking for - something like this maybe??

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.FetchPreviousRow @ID INT
AS BEGIN

   SELECT TOP 1 ID, (other columns.....)
   FROM dbo.TableB
   WHERE ID < @ID
   ORDER BY ID DESC

END
```

This will select the row with the biggest ID *less than* the `@ID` you pass in, so:

```
EXEC dbo.FetchPreviousRow @ID = 5
```

will return the row with `ID = 4` - if it exists. Otherwise, it will return the row with `ID = 3` - if it exists. Otherwise the row with `ID = 2` - and so on....

Answer (score 1):

How about selecting all ID's less than 5 and sorting them by ID.  The first result then would be the one you want.